# Is it possible to transfer data to SQL Server from an unconventional database

Tags: sql, sql-server, stream, named-pipes, service-broker

My company has a SQL Server database which they would like to populate with data from a hierarchical database (as opposed to relational). I have already written a .net application to map its schema to a relational database and have successfully done that. However my problem is that the tech being used here is so old that I see no obvious way of data transfer.

However, I have certain ideas about how I can do this. This involves having to write file scans in my unconventional database and dump out files as csv. Then do a bulk upload into SQL Server. I do not appreciate this as there is the element of invalid data involved which terminates the bulk upload quite so often.

I was hoping to explore options around service broker. I was hoping to dump out live transactions where a record has changed in my database and then this can somehow be picked up?

Secondly I was also hoping to use something which if I dump out live or changed records in a file (I can format the file to whatever format is needed), can something suck it into SQL Server?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Waqar

Comment: Please add details of the type of system you are extracting data from.  What type of database is it?  Does it even have a name?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with? I ask becasue that will have an impact on the available options such as SSIS and the XML data type, for example.

Comment: Database type we are using is called RTM and its written in ZUG/ZOPL. We are using sql server 2008 standard edition

Answer (score 1):

Service Broker is a very powerful queue/messaging management system. I am not sure why you want to use it for this.

You can set up an SSIS job that keeps checking a folder for csv files and when detects a new one it reads it into SQL Server and then zips it and archives it somewhere else. This is very common. SSIS can then either process the data (its a wonderful ETL tool) or  invoke procedures in SQL Server to process the data. SSIS is very fast and is rarely overwhelmed so why would you use Service Broker?

If its IMS (mainframe) type data you have to convert it to flat tables and then as csv type text tables for SQL Server to read.

SQL server is very good at processing XML and, as of 2016, JSON shaped data, so if that is your data type you can directly import into SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Skip bulk insert.  The SQL Server `xml` data type lends itself to doing what you're doing.  If you can output data from your other system into an XML format, you can push that XML directly into an argument for a stored procedure.

After that, you can use the [functions for the XML type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-type-and-columns-sql-server) to iterate through the data as needed.